# Do Superior Ki-Focus items work on weapon attacks when made through a weapon?

Tags: dnd-4e, weapons, implements

I was considering the idea of the Superior Implement Training when I realized nowhere that I can find specifies something in particular about a Superior Implement of Ki Focus when used as a weapon (I did find one though for just a Ki Focus used as a weapon).

If we use the example [Iron Ki Focus](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=3592), would the Deadly property work on a longsword with a weapon attack (Such as Melee Basic Attack) or would that fall in line with the implement power usage?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, superior implement bonuses only apply to powers with the `Implement` keyword.

From PHB3, page 195:

> A superior implement's properties apply only to attacks made with the implement. They affect only implement powers, even if an implement can be used to make weapon attacks.

Comment: In front of me the whole time and I missed it.  Thanks.